# I lost bitcoin in core bitcoin account, pls help

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I installed bitcoin core to drive d, then I cut all the files into a new file. bitcoin core gets synced from scratch and then i no longer coin in wallet. Please show me how to recover the bitcoin number, I would like to thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you moved the Bitcoin Core data directory without telling Bitcoin Core that you had done so, then Bitcoin Core will not use the files that you moved and instead just make new ones. This means that it synced the blockchain entirely from scratch and generated a new wallet file. In order to access your Bitcoin, you need to move your wallet.dat file back to the data directory or tell Bitcoin Core that the data directory has changed by setting the `-datadir=<path>` option in its startup command.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. The problem is that I copy the file wallet.dat so when the file sync is overwritten?Please tell me a bit more about your solution, since I have 1BTC in it, that's all the money you borrow. Your situation is very dangerous, looking forward to your help.

Comment: Now I only have the wallet.dat file generated by the second sync, not sure. Looking forward to your help, I thank you 0.2BTC for you

Comment: please give me gmail for contact!Because I do not spend on this technology.

Comment: If you had moved the wallet.dat file elsewhere (not copied, moved, so there was no wallet.dat file afterwards), then a new one will be created. If not, then the wallet.dat file will be used. Either way, I suggest that you copy your original wallet.dat file and put that copy back into the datadir.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I did not have the original wallet.dat file because I cut the wallet file to the new file